# How to add class on element where if condition is true in for loop in angular template?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have worked on angular 4 project. In this project, I have requirement to add class on element that is created by for loop. But I want to add class dynamically only once, means when condition meets first time it add the class on element, but after that if same condition meet again it don't add class. I have looking around my articles but not get any solution. If anyone know about please let me know. Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let car of cars">
   <div *ngIf="car.name == 'audi'">
      // WHEN FIRST TIME CAR NAME IS EQUAL TO AUDI THEN ADD 'first-luxury-car' class on div.
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
cards = [
   {"name": "maruti", "model": "Alto"},
   {"name": "audi", "model": "A1" },
   {"name": "audi", "model": "A5" }
];
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. [ask]

Comment: have you tried what I suggested? it's nice to have a feedback to help the community.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the local variables `index`, `first` and `ngClass` to achieve what you want. Like this

```
 <ng-container*ngFor="let car of cars; index as i; first as isFirst">   
   <div [ngClass]="{'first-luxury-car': isFirst || cars[i].name !== cars[i-1].name}">
        {{car.name}}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

So...it doesn't matter which car is, it will apply the class only for the first occurrence of it.
Just check if the actual one is different from the previous and that's it...the `isFirst` is needed because the first item of the list will always have it class set

See working in this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/f3e1yQtKKACyeYRWxzJf?p=preview
Hope it helps.

Comment: I want first displaying tab to be selected.

Comment: please check it.

Comment: This is not what you've asked. If the answer works for your first question, please mark as accepted/upvote then make a new question. And then not only me but others members could help you. You can send me the link of the new question when you create it